# Looking for clustering message framework for Python

Tags: python, p2p, cluster-computing, distributed-objects

I'm looking for a messaging framework to build up a cluster in Python (something similar to Apache Tribes).

Are there any such frameworks in Python?

Comment: This can be closed as "Seeking Recommendations".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not too familiar with Apache Tribes but have you looked at Pyro?

http://www.xs4all.nl/~irmen/pyro3/